# RESTlet tutorial application does not return Java Objects (JSON only)

Tags: android, google-app-engine, restlet-2.0

I've been looking the source code available from the Restlet [official tutorial](http://wiki.restlet.org/docs_2.0/13-restlet/21-restlet/318-restlet/303-restlet.html).

I am trying to hit the Restlet server using the Android app from he tutorial adn I only get the JSON response, not the Java Object. I tried using all libraries and extensions, nothing works. When I hit the tutorial url though ( http://restlet-example-serialization.appspot.com/contacts/123) I get the desired response. Any ideas? BTW, I am just using the server (GAE) in the example, not the GWT frontend.

Comment: Also, the Java SE client works fine. It's just the Android client that is not working.

Answer (score -1):

Use GSOn to convert json to java object. GSON you can get from google as its their code:

http://code.google.com/p/google-gson/

Other way:

```
Response res = client.handle(req); 
    ObjectRepresentation<Item> obj = new ObjectRepresentation<Item>(res.getEntity()); 
    Item item = obj.getObject();
```

Comment: I do not want to do that.  In theory, the beauty of Restlet is that you are dealing with Java objects only and you don't have to serialize/deserialize. Any other ideas?

Comment: The other way is:   Response res = client.handle(req); 
        ObjectRepresentation<Item> obj = new ObjectRepresentation<Item>(res.getEntity()); 
        Item item = obj.getObject();

Comment: So in the Android client, the tutorial has this piece of code: contact = resource.retrieve(); where contact is of type Contact and Resource is of type ContactServerResource. How does your code replace that? And why does this code work when I access the estlet-example-serialization app but not when I deploy the code under my app in GAE?